# insert multiple rows in same database table using servlet jsp in eclipse

Tags: java, sql, jsp, servlets, jstl

I m trying insert multiple rows in same database (each row had many fields) on submit but unable to do so. I m successfully able to insert single row but when it comes for multiple rows I got stuck.

This is the jsp page where you take an input to dynamically add no of rows. There is no separate submit button for each row instead single submit button to insert all rows.

1.> **projmgrsuccessful.jsp**

```
<form name="allocate-project-task" action="AddProjectTaskDAO" method="get"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<h4>Another popup</h4>
<input type="hidden" name="proj_emp_comt" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="pid" value="<c:out value="${pid}" />">

<label>Enter the no of employee involved in project</label>
<input type="text" id="textbox1" />
<input type="button" value="Add" id="add" />

<table border="1" id="pt-tabledata">
</table>

<center><input type="submit" name="alloc_time" value="Allocate"><a href="#"  id="closea">Close</a></center>
</form>
<script>
$("#add").click(function() {
$('#pt-tabledata').append('<tr><td>Username</td><td>Work description</td> <td>Allocate time</td><td>Allocate work and time</td></tr>');
for (var i = 0; i < $("#textbox1").val(); i++) {
    $newdiv2 = $('<tr id="pt-ip-row" style="display:block;"><td><select name="uname"><c:forEach items="${ual}" var="u"><option value="<c:out value="${u.uname}"></c:out>"><c:out value="${u.uname}"></c:out></option> </c:forEach>              </select></td><td><textarea rows="5" cols="15" name="pdesc_emp"></textarea></td><td><input type="text" name="pestd_time_alloc" /></td><td></td><td><a href="#" id="close-pt-row" onclick="return hide();">Close</a></td> </tr>').after("#add");
    $('#pt-tabledata').append($newdiv2);
}
});
</script>
```

This is java code snippet where I processing the data like connecting to the database and inserting it into database table.

2.> **AddProjectTaskDAO.java**

```
package com.pms.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection; 
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
* Servlet implementation class AddProjectTaskDAO
*/
@WebServlet("/AddProjectTaskDAO")
public class AddProjectTaskDAO extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public AddProjectTaskDAO() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    response.setContentType("text/html");  
    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter(); 

    Connection conn=null;
    String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbName="projectmanagement";
    String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String dbUsername="root";
    String dbPassword="root";

    try{  

          String Projid=" ";
          String Projuname=" ";
          String Projdesc_emp=" ";
          String Projestd_time_alloc=" ";
          String Projtask_emp_comment=" ";
          String Pid[] = request.getParameterValues("pid");  
          String Uname[] = request.getParameterValues("uname");  
          String Pdesc_emp[] = request.getParameterValues("pdesc_emp"); 
          String Pestd_time_alloc[] =  request.getParameterValues("pestd_time_alloc");
          String Projtask_emp_cmnt[] = request.getParameterValues("ptask_emp_cmnt");  
          //String Utype = request.getParameter("utype");

          for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
              Projid=Pid[i]+" "+ 1;
              Projuname=Uname[i]+" "+ 1;
              Projdesc_emp=Pdesc_emp[i]+" "+ 1;
              Projestd_time_alloc=Pestd_time_alloc[i]+" "+ 1;
              Projtask_emp_comment=Projtask_emp_cmnt[i]+" "+ 1;
              }

          Class.forName(driver);  
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,dbUsername, dbPassword);
          Statement st=conn.createStatement();


          int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into projtaskallocate (pid,uname,ptdesc_emp,ptestd_time_alloc,ptask_emp_cmnt) values ('" +Projid+ "','" +Projuname+"','" +Projdesc_emp+ "','" +Projestd_time_alloc+ "','" +Projtask_emp_comment+ "')");

          String msg=" ";
          if(i!=0){  
          UserPMDAO dd = new UserPMDAO();
          request.setAttribute("ual", dd.getUsers());
          ProjectDAO pp = new ProjectDAO();
          request.setAttribute("pal", pp.getProjects());  
          String nextJSP = "/projmgrsuccessful.jsp"; 
          RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP); 
          dispatcher.forward(request,response);



          }  
          else
          {  
              msg="Failed to Add Project";
              pw.print("<font size='6' color=blue>" + msg + "</font>");
          }  
          pw.close();
          //pst.close();
          st.close();
          conn.close();
        }  
        catch (Exception e)
        {  
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        }  

}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



}

}
```

Here the the problem is when I click on submit button only first row is inserted but my requirement is to insert all the rows.

Please help and if I m going wrong please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Batch statements to insert multiple rows using `jdbc` ,

```
for (int i=0:i<100;i++) {
    String query = "insert into projtaskallocate (pid,uname,ptdesc_emp,ptestd_time_alloc,ptask_emp_cmnt) values ('" +Projid+ "','" +Projuname+"','" +Projdesc_emp+ "','" +Projestd_time_alloc+ "','" +Projtask_emp_comment+ "')";
    statement.addBatch(query);
}
statement.executeBatch();
statement.close();
connection.close();
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: san krish I added those statement but it is not working.

Comment: I got reason why I was receiving NullPointerException because request.getParameterValues() was unable to get the values.
This was also may be because I have dynamically created textboxes.
Please can help me out how to get textbox values from dynamically created textboxes.

Comment: For which fields you get `null` values . check while submitting the forms . whether values are sent

Comment: I sysout all the fields and got all the dynamically added rows are getting null values

Comment: Can you please how how to get dynamically added textbox values (which I created using jquery) to servlet

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your for loop. The values read from parameter array are overwritten for each iteration and the variables will have only last element values. Use the below code.

```
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,dbUsername, dbPassword);

    String query = "insert into projtaskallocate (pid,uname,ptdesc_emp,ptestd_time_alloc,ptask_emp_cmnt) values (?,?,?,?,?)";

    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){

         Projid=Pid[i]+" "+ 1;

         Projuname=Uname[i]+" "+ 1;

         --

         --

         pstmt.setString(1, Projid);

         pstmt.setString(2, Projuname);

         --

         --

         pstmt.addBatch();

    }

    pstmt.executeBatch();
```

http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparedstatement-example-batch-update/